# unnexpected increment of count in multithreaded program

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, libcurl

I am trying to run given number of curls from each thread. `pull_one_url()` is the function which is called in `pthread_create()` from `main()`. `cnt_limit` is a global variable which is set in main and read only in threads.

The unexpected behavior I am seeing sometimes is that the local count variable get incremented to high values.

For given run number of threads were 10 and `cnt_limit` (number of curls from each thread) set to 10.

Command line run: `./a.out 10 10 10.140.71.12`

The unexpected output is:

```
10 2682
10 2858
10 2804
10 2988
10 2871
10 2940
10 2864
10 2609
10 2816
10 2893
```

expected output: for given input each 10 threads need to perform 10 curl requests.

number of lines = number of threads

first number in each line = number of curl requests each thread require to perform.

second number in each line = count of curl requests each thread performed.

```
10 10
10 10
10 10
10 10
10 10
10 10
10 10
10 10
10 10
10 10
```

The source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t write_data(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
//    printf("got response\n");
    return size * nmemb;
}
int cnt_limit;
static void *pull_one_url(void *url)
{
    CURL *curl;
    int cnt;
    int count = 0;
    for (cnt=0; cnt < cnt_limit; cnt++) {
        CURLcode res;
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        int response_code;
        if (res == CURLE_OK) {
            curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
            //printf("%d\n", response_code);
        }
        else {
            //printf("400\n");
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        count++;
        //printf("%d\n", cnt);
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", cnt_limit, count);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    cnt_limit=atoi(argv[2]);
    pthread_t tid[n];
    int i;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    for(i = 0; i< n; i++) {
        int error = pthread_create(&tid[i],
                               NULL,
                               pull_one_url,
                               (void *) argv[3]);
        if(0 != error)
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't run thread number %d, errno %d\n", i, error);
        //else
            //fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d, gets %s\n", i, argv[2]);
    }

    /* now wait for all threads to terminate */
    for(i = 0; i< n; i++) {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
        //fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d terminated\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

compile: `gcc source_code.c -lpthread -lcurl`

run : `./a.out 10 10 <url>`

Edited: After commenting out libcurl code present inside loop, i don't observe this behavior yet. But previously observed unexpected behavior was also not very consistent. question still remain how this libcurl code affecting the simple counter in loop.

After spending a lot of time trying to understand this I am posting it here. I think i am making some silly mistake. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is cnt_limit ever assigned a value?

Comment: yes @jmq , it is assigned in main() function

Comment: What happened when you had `printf("%d\n", cnt);` in each loop instead of the commented-out `//printf("%d\n", cnt);`?  Did you get only 10 loops?  What do you get if you change that to something like `printf("%d %d\n", cnt, count);`?  That would tell you if `cnt` and/or `count` is getting overwritten somehow.

Comment: what are your command line arguments? Same behavior with only 1 thread? Are you sure simply passing `void*` into `curl_easy_setopt` is ok? [This](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) source says _That parameter can be a long, a function pointer, an object pointer or a curl_off_t, depending on what the specific option expects. Read this manual carefully as bad input values may cause libcurl to behave badly!_

Comment: hi @AndrewHenle, when i print cnt and count together, cnt stays for long time to 0 while count keep incrementing.

Comment: hi @yano, command line arguments are ./a.out 10 10 10.140.71.12 
after commenting out curl code i don't observe this behavior. but how curl code affecting a simple counter ?

Comment: Then it seems the problem lies in the curl code, most certainly the way you're using it. "Behave badly" probably means undefined behavior, which is manifesting here as writing over memory it doesn't own or something... that's my guess anyway. As it says, read the curl documentation carefully, make sure you are using it correctly.

Comment: How well does it work single-threaded?  I strongly suspect a race condition in the curl code.  As @yano stated, you may be misusing one or more of the curl functions, although I can't see any obvious misuses.  Also make sure to error-check all your curl function calls.

Comment: Read this: [libcurl thread safety](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html). The most important thing, which is calling `curl_global_init()` before doing any multithreading, has been done in your code. However, there are other things mentioned on that page, for example that the memory functions must also be thread-safe, otherwise you must use [curl_global_init_mem()](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init_mem.html).

Comment: I suggest that you also check all return values (especially the one from [curl_easy_init](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html)) to see if it reports an error. If it does, then the thread should print an error message and immediately abort. If `curl == NULL` then you should not pass that value to other curl functions.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a stack underflow, add int count_pre = 0; before and int count_post = 0 after the int count = 0; and in the inner look print all 3.

Comment: According to the [curl documentation on `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE.html), the last parameter of `curl_easy_get_info` is of type `long *`. However, you are passing a parameter of type `int *`. Is `sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)` on your platform? If not, then it is likely overwriting a neighboring variable on the stack.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes you are correct, after changing response_code type to long it working fine. i think problem was what you mentioned.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh: On what platform are you running your program? In particular, what operating system, CPU and compiler are you using? On most common platforms, `sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)`, that's why I am quite surprised that this was the cause. Can you insert the line `printf( "%d %d", sizeof(long), sizeof(int) );` into your program and tell me the output?

Comment: @SaurabhSingh: If `sizeof(long)` is not identical to `sizeof(int)` on your platform, then the problem is likely to be something else and you were just lucky that the problem hasn't occured again. Therefore, it is important that you test it by inserting the `printf` statement that I mentioned in my last comment into your code.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh: I just noticed that my statement that on most common platforms `sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)` is incorrect. According to [this page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/size-of-long-integer-type-on-different-architecture-and-os), `sizeof(long) == 8` on Linux targetting 64-bit CPUs, whereas `sizeof(int) == 4`. That is most likely the reason for your problem. However, I can't confirm this until you tell me the output of `printf( "%d %d", sizeof(long), sizeof(int) );`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, sorry for the late response. i verified sizeof(int) and sizeof(long) they are 4 and 8 respectively. the case you mentioned it seems that was the problem. after changing response code type to long. i didn't saw unexpected behavior. thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the results of the discussion in the comments section, it seems the problem was the following:

Part of the code that the OP posted was the following:

```
int response_code;
[...]
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
```

According to the [curl documentation on CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE.html), the last parameter is of type `long *`. However, the OP was passing a parameter of type `int *`. Since the OP is using a platform on which `sizeof(long) == 8` whereas `sizeof(int) == 4`, the curl library wrote 8 bytes to the address of `response_code`, although only 4 bytes had been allocated on the stack for this variable. This likely caused a neighboring variable on the stack to be overwritten.

To fix this problem, the line

`int response_code;`

should be changed to:

`long response_code;`